# Get Cell ID and LAC in CDMA BlackBerry devices (OS5 and greater)

Tags: java, blackberry, cdma

I am stuck on how to get `CellID` and `LAC` in `CDMA` BlackBerry devices supporting OS 5 and greater.  I have to get Latitude and Longitude without using GPS. So, i have implemented the solution for GPRS devices, but for CDMA devices i am unable to map CellID and LAC.

I did read many posts on this forum and others saying that CDMA Info provided `BID = CellID` and `NID = LAC`, but it never worked at all, and I also tried different combinations for LAC such as using SID as LAC, but it also didn't work.

How can I get Cell ID on OS 5.0+ BlackBerry devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
int MCC = RadioInfo.getMCC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex());
int MNC = RadioInfo.getMNC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex());
int LAC = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC();
int CELLID = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getCellInfo() to get both LAC & CellId. Just call the respective methods:

```
int LAC = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC();
int CELLID = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId();
```

Comment: @Author please select the right a answer and give us upvotes :P